# Is there a Skyrim command to check if a player knows a spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I am thinking about making a mod for Skyrim. One thing that this mod hinges on is checking if a player already knows a spell. I have been looking high and low for a script command, but have yet to find one.

Is there a script command somewhere that can check this? For example, something that would allow this:

```
If player."HasSpell" spellid {
  player.RemoveSpell spellid
} else {
  player.AddSpell spellid
}
```

...or something to that effect. If there isn't a command, can anyone think of alternatives/workarounds to accomplishing this?

Comment: Hard to propose alternatives when we don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Frank, he's looking for a console command that tells him if the player knows a specific spell or not. At least that's how I understood the question.

Comment: @Nolonar Without any inkling of what he's trying to do.  I'm merely pointing out that without knowing what it is he's trying to accomplish, we can't very well provide alternatives or workarounds.  All we can do is tell him if the command exists or not.

Comment: Sorry, I want a script to run when a book is opened and there to be an if/else event depending on whether or not the player knows a certain spell.

Example:

If player."hasspell" <spellid> {
   (player knows spell result)
}else{
   (player doesn not know spell result)
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In Papyrus, the player is (usually) represented as just another `Actor`, and [`Actor` objects have a `HasSpell` method](http://www.creationkit.com/HasSpell_-_Actor) you can call on them, passing the form of the spell in question. This will return true or false depending on whether or not the actor knows the spell represented by the supplied form.